# Recorded user authentication then run same script with another user id and password but Jmeter displaying previous user's dashboard

Tags: jmeter

Recorded user authentication for one user then run script in Jmeter and successfully logged-in. Now change user id and password  for another user but displaying previous user information not changed user information

Answer (score 0):

1. Check out if there are any [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) being sent via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager). It might be the case your application under test identifies user via header
2. Check if recorded URLs contain dynamic postfix which can act as user session identifier
3. If there is a [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) in your Test Plan - update username and password there
4. Consider adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) to our Test Plan - it should be sufficient to automatically handle user sessions
5. Generic troubleshooting step: capture the requests sent by JMeter and the real browser using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compare them. Amend JMeter configuration to eliminate differences.